# Android Jsoup post request to ASPX page always get 500 error

Tags: android, asp.net, jsoup

I want to develop a parking fee app, as a result I have to parse some data from websites. I tried several websites and succeed, but I always get a 500 error in this [webpage](http://tcparking.taichung.gov.tw/Parking/Parking/ParkingFee.aspx).
The following is my code

```
Connection.Response resource = Jsoup.connect("http://tcparking.taichung.gov.tw/Parking/Parking/ParkingFee.aspx")
    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
    .execute();
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://tcparking.taichung.gov.tw/Parking/Parking/ParkingFee.aspx")
    .data("__VIEWSTATE", resource.parse().getElementById("__VIEWSTATE").val())
    .data("__EVENTVALIDATION", resource.parse().getElementById("__EVENTVALIDATION").val())
    .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$car_no", "ALZ-3586")
    .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CarType", "C")
    .data("__EVENTTARGET:", "")
    .data("__EVENTARGUMENT:", "")
    .data("__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED:", "")
    .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    .cookies(resource.cookies())
    .post();
```

However, I always get

```
W/System.err: org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=500, URL=http://tcparking.taichung.gov.tw/Parking/Parking/ParkingFee.aspx
W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:537)
W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:493)
W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:205)
W/System.err:     at com.lai.smith.parkingfee.asyncparse.AsyncTaizhong.doInBackground(AsyncTaizhong.java:54)
W/System.err:     at com.lai.smith.parkingfee.asyncparse.AsyncTaizhong.doInBackground(AsyncTaizhong.java:23)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

At the same time, I can successfully access the website with chrome extension-[postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop)
---------------------------Pic1----------------------------

[image]

---------------------------Pic2----------------------------

[image]

I tried to add everything in jsoup just like what I added in postman, but I still get 500 error, can anyone help me figure out what was wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in the data of the form. There is a invalid `colon` at the end of three data parameters. The ASP.Net server is thus unable to find the arguments `__EVENTTARGET`, `__EVENTTARGET` and `__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED`.

Replace the three following lines

```
.data("__EVENTTARGET:", "")
.data("__EVENTARGUMENT:", "")
.data("__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED:", "")
```

with

```
.data("__EVENTTARGET", "")
.data("__EVENTARGUMENT", "")
.data("__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED", "")
```

I tested your original code with this tweak and Jsoup post request to ASPX page now gets 200 OK code.